# iterating through each word in a richtextbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to iterate through each word in a text document to compare each word to a list of names using the following code.

```
            For Each word As String In TextBox1.Text.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            Replace(word, vbCrLf, "")
            word = Trim(TrimPunctuation(word))
            MsgBox(word)
            next

Private Function TrimPunctuation(ByVal value As String) As String
    Dim removeFromStart As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To value.Length - 1 Step 1
        If Char.IsPunctuation(value(i)) Then
            removeFromStart += 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Dim removeFromEnd As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = value.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Char.IsPunctuation(value(i)) Then
            removeFromEnd += 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return Trim(value.Substring(removeFromStart,
                           value.Length - removeFromEnd - removeFromStart))
End Function
```

For the most part it is working, but at the end of each sentence, it returns the last word including punctuation and the carriage return and the first word of the next sentence.

> > Dinner.
>
> Then

Comment: Try with something like `\w\w*`. It doesn't work if you have names like `O'Leary`. Or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I created a list to hold the output.
Next I removed any hard returns.
The line is split into words. The small c following the  space character tells the compiler that this is a Char which is what the Split function is expecting.
I created a Char array of punctuation. You may want to add additional characters.
I looped through the words, trimming the punctuation. Then the punctuation free words were added to the clean list.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim CleanList As New List(Of String)
    Dim RemovedNewLine = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(vbLf, " ")
    Dim words = RemovedNewLine.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim punc() As Char = {","c, "."c, "?"c, "!"c}
    For Each word In words
        Dim TrimmedWord = word.Trim(punc)
        CleanList.Add(TrimmedWord)
    Next
    For Each word In CleanList
        Debug.Print(word)
    Next
End Sub
```